# Android Any API for Speech to Text for android 2.3 or above which works offline?

Tags: android, api, speech-recognition, offline, android-2.3-gingerbread

I need Offline Speech Recognition and Speech to Text API. I have found sphinx android client, but its much expensive for RAM and Processor for android phones having API level 8.
Is there any library or any help regarding this?

Comment: Might be related :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893788/use-offline-voice-to-text-in-android-4-1-jelly-bean-from-my-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

API (Application Programming Interface) generally infers that you are connecting to a server online.

CMU's PocketSphinx probably is your best option as far as offline Speech To Text on Android, because it was specifically made with low powered devices in mind. I think that PocketSphinx is different from Sphinx client for Android that you referenced.

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2013/01/pocketsphinx-for-android-in-google-play/